# Team Foundation Server 2013 - TF900547 Error after upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Seen a few links towards this error:

TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid

After upgrading out enviroment from TFS 2012 to 2013 we have has the above erros while running some builds. I have seen some threads mentioning that you need to install Visual Studio on the TFS Server and our seperate Build server - does this resolve the issue?

Unable to switch to MS Test as the test runner as it is greyed out for some reason ??? This was working in previous versions but not in VS2013

why does TFS 2013 require me installing VS2013 on both TFS Server and our Build server if the threads i have seen for the solution are correct ?

Comment: Please add links to those threads.